# Dialogflow v2 android sdk - Add QueryParameters to QueryInput

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, dialogflow-es

i'm actually trying to use Dialogflow v2 with java sdk in android.

I can already make queries to dialogflow but I wanted to send some payload with my query.
Because of this, I discovered the **QueryParameters** object and I already set it with my desired payload.

The problem is, I have both **QueryInput** and **QueryParameters** defined but there is no documentation (or code references in the source code) about how to apply the parameters to the input before trying to detect the intent.

```
SessionsClient.create().use { sessionsClient ->
            // Set the session name using the sessionId (UUID) and projectID
            val session = SessionName.of(PROJECT_ID, UUID)

            System.out.println("Session Path: $session")

            // Set the text (input) and language code (en) for the query
            val textInput = TextInput.newBuilder().setText(text).setLanguageCode(LANGUAGE_CODE)

            // Build the query with the TextInput
            val queryInput = QueryInput.newBuilder().setText(textInput).build()

            // Set payload
            val payload = "{someid: $someid}"
            val queryParameters = QueryParameters.newBuilder().setPayload(Struct.parseFrom(payload.toByteArray())).build()

            // (HERE I NEED TO ADD THE PARAMETERS TO INPUT)


            // Performs the detect intent request
            val response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput)

            // returns the query result
            return response.queryResult
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of deep searching, I managed to find the **DetectIntentRequest** class.

```
            //Build the request
            val request = DetectIntentRequest.newBuilder()
                .setSession(session.toString())
                .setQueryInput(queryInput)
                .setQueryParams(queryParameters)
                .build()

            // Performs the detect intent request
            val response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(request)
```

> Note: if you are using other languages probably you 'll have a third
>   parameter in detectIntent function to place your queryParameters

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin ,

```
val queryInput1211 = QueryInput.newBuilder()
            .setText(TextInput.newBuilder().setText(msg).setLanguageCode("en-US"))
            .setEvent(com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.EventInput.newBuilder()
                    .setName("Welcome")
                    .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                    .setParameters(
                            Struct.newBuilder().putFields("user_id",
                                    Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("1234").build())
                                    .build())
                    .build())
            .build()
```

For java

```
QueryInput queryInput1211 = QueryInput.newBuilder()
                    .setText(TextInput.newBuilder().setText(msg).setLanguageCode("en-US"))
                    .setEvent(com.google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.EventInput.newBuilder()
                            .setName("Welcome")
                            .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                            .setParameters(
                                    Struct.newBuilder().putFields("user_id",
                                            Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("1234").build())
                                            .build())
                            .build())
                    .build();
```

Where `Welcome` is intent event name and `user_id` as parameter name